# How to Convert Packet to TcpPacket?

Tags: c#, packet-capture, sharppcap, packetdotnet

I'm using PacketDotNet to resolving captured packets. In PacketDotNet0.12.0, it provides a method called `GetEncapsulated`.

```
TcpPacket tcppacket = TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(this.packet);
```

But now, I have to update PacketDotNet from version 0.12.0 to version 1.3.0.0. And the new version doesn't have  **`TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated()`** method. I can not find any documentation about PacketDotNet or demos about it.

So I want to know how can I get a TcpPacket objct from a Packet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

```
PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket().Extract<T>()
```

method

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way:

var tcpPacket = packet.Extract<PacketDotNet.TcpPacket>();//TcpPacket

var udpPacket= packet.Extract<PacketDotNet.UdpPacket>();//UdpPacket